# Issues with the labels in image in matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, label

I have to show a confusion matrix with corresponding labels in an image. I am using matplotlib for the same. But when the image is created it shows only alternative labels and all the labels are not shown. Also the data in the matrix get overlapped with the other grid data. Is shall be thankful for the help.

```
labels_x = ['D','F','A','G','DG','R','I','BS','COA','W','T','UserAcc%'] #create labels  for each classes
labels_y = ['D','F','A','G','DG','R','I','BS','COA','W','T','ProdAcc%']
# Guassian Confusion Matrix plo
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 18))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(cm1 )

pl.title('CONFUSION MATRIX(Guassian)')
for i,j in ((x,y) for x in xrange(len(cm1))
        for y in xrange(len(cm1[0]))):
    ax.annotate(str(cm1[j][i]),xy=(i,j))
fig.colorbar(cax)
ax.set_xticklabels(['']+labels_x)
ax.set_yticklabels(['']+labels_y)
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.set_cmap('Pastel1')
plt.savefig(finaldata_path_plot+"GuassianConfusionMatrix.pdf", format ='pdf')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image: Confusion matrix image with alternate labels and overlapped data]

Comment: Just simply reading the document would perfectly answer your own question:-)

Comment: Yes i know i am doing some mistake in subplot but i am unable to figure it out.I will again see it.

Comment: Yes i got it .. i have to add set_xtick() and set_ytick()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, matplotlib automatically chooses tick locations at "even" intervals.  Tick labels only occur at tick locations, so if you'd like to label every column and row, you'll need to set the tick positions as well as the tick labels.

Basically, you want something like:

```
i = range(len(labels))
ax.set(xticks=i, xticklabels=labels, yticks=i, yticklabels=labels)
```

As a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['D', 'F', 'A', 'G', 'DG', 'R', 'I', 'BS', 'COA', 'W', 'T']
data = np.random.random((len(labels), len(labels)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.matshow(data, cmap='Pastel1')
fig.colorbar(im)

i = range(len(labels))
ax.set(xticks=i, xticklabels=labels, yticks=i, yticklabels=labels)

for (i, j), z in np.ndenumerate(data):
    ax.text(j, i, '{:0.1f}'.format(z), ha='center', va='center')

ax.set(ylabel='True label', xlabel='Predicted label', title='Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()
```

[image]